# Transferring Files from one remote server to another remote server using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-ise

I am trying to transfer all files in a single directory from one server to another. The code I had working looked like this.

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\$Remoteservername\e$\SomeProgram\Documents\ExportedFiles\*"  -Destination "\\$serverImRunningPowerShellOn\d$\File_Download\"
```

This worked for 1 day then I started to receive an error the day after. Then the next day, without changing anything, it runs but only grabs the file names inside E:\SomeProgram\Documents\ExportedFiles.

I have tried other methods and received WinRM errors. I then tried passing credentials, that did not work nor adding the server im on to the other servers (the one where im pulling files from) Trusted Hosts List.

I want a script that transfers all of the files in the Exported Files directory on Server A to Server B (the one im remoted into).

Any ideas on how to do this the right way?

EDIT: It was a recurse issue. It worked for a short period of time but now I am getting this error.

> Copy-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Invalid Path: '\$Remoteservername\e$\SomeProgram\Documents\ExportedFiles*'.

I swear this worked for about 6 runs. Then just stopped working. I know the path is valid.

Comment: What errors are being returned?  That's important information when you're asking for help on a problem like this...

Comment: try adding `-recurse` to the end of the command

Comment: "it runs but only grabs the file names inside E:\SomeProgram\Documents\ExportedFiles." - what did you expect it to do?

Comment: It was a recuse issue, thank you for your help. I wanted it to download all the files within that directory. I had it working for a short time but now I am getting an error.